# SelectedItem changed and commands in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, command

I'm new in Silverlight and I have some issues regarding Commands. I have a DataGrid which is bound to ObservableCollection in my ViewModel. I also have a button

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add</Button>
```

which Command property is bound to command of ViewModel. 
Command class looks like that

```
public class GenericCommand : ICommand
    {

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
        private bool previousState;
        public GenericCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;

        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (canExecute == null) return false;
            bool currentState = canExecute(parameter);
            if (currentState != previousState)
            {
                previousState = currentState;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
                return currentState;
            }
            return currentState;

        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (execute == null) return;
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

property AddCommand was created this way

```
AddCommand = new GenericCommand(Add,CanAdd);
 public bool CanAdd(object param)
        {
            return SelectedItem != null;
        }
    public void Add(object param)
        {

        }
```

The problem is that it seems that CommandBinding don't react to changes of SelectedItem. If I run my applicatiopn none of grid rows are selected, I can see that CanAdd function is invoked. However if I click on some item CanAdd function is not invoked - despite the fact that I can see that property SelectedItem in view model has changed ?? What do I do wrong ?
Is it possible to use commands without using some external library ?
I used to write similar code in WPF however in WPF in GeneriCommand class I used

```
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that in Silverlight there is no such thing like CommandManager.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel will need to implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface.  Also the CanAdd method needs to be changed to something like this.

```
if (SelectedItem == null)
{
     base.AddValidationErrorMessage("SelectedItem", "Select something....");
     return false;
}
else
{
     base.RemoveValidationErrorMessage("SelectedItem");
     return true;
 }
```

Also take a look at these articles, I think you will find them helpful.

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2010/01/09/silverlight-about-validation-when-binding-to-custom-forms-part-2-using-silverlight-4.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-and-asynchronous-validation-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx